# Is there a way to get all controller mapping to a single file

Tags: spring-rest

We are using spring @Controller annotation to create API endpoints in our service. During build start up all the mappings are printed in console but we need to capture this info in a file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a file appender to your logging framework, for the specific package. This is how you would do in Logback.

```
<appender name="ControllerMappingFile"         
 class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOGS}/yourlogfilename.log</file>
    <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
<appender>
<logger name="o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">           
    <appender-ref ref="ControllerMappingFile"/>
</logger>
```